# How I can send data from ReactJS to Outlook Template?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, templates, office365

I need to fill the subject, and part of the body with some information from an outlook template. This information is in the FrontEnd which is built in React and Javascript.
I don't know if it is possible to send the data or the text I need from the frontEnd to the outlook template.

I can't send it using some mail API (nodemail,etc) because the sender is different each time.

Example:

**Frontend**
Subject: "Happy Holidays"

Part of body to add: " on this summer"

**Outlook template**
Subject: #newSubjectFromJS
Body: "Have fun " + #partOfBodyFromJS

I have tried to send the email from my backEnd, however the possibility to make modifications, such as adding images in the body of the email, attachments, etc., is lost.
In addition to the fact that the recipients are usually groups that are already attached to the templates. And doing it this way does not allow me to have access to the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automating Outlook from a web application is not possible because only Internet Explorer is aware about the ActiveX technology. Web developers can use the [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol using which you can specify the subject, body and etc. For example:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?
    subject=MessageTitle&amp;
    body=Message Content">
    Contact Us</a>
```

Also you may consider using the Graph API for sending emails programmatically if you use Office 365, see [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for more information.

Comment: Ty,I was not sure if it could be automated. I will use another way to get the result I want.